# IIS Server files Updated, but it is not updated in web browser view source. Why?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I deployed the web application in asp.net, there's one file named `default.aspx` that contains one script(ex : `alert('dfdf');`).

I removed the script and deployed again. The deployed `default.aspx` file doesn't contain the script. But after I copied the `default.aspx` file in `Inetpub/wwwroot` and access the page through web browser and checked view source : the script is present.

But, in `Inetpub/wwwroot/default.aspx` doesn't contain any script. I refreshed and restarted my IIS server and my machine too.

May I know why this happen to me? Help me guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have the page on browser cache.

If you use google chrome, open the browser tools, then keep the click on the reload button for 3 seconds and a menu opens to gives you some option, like "hard reload" means that it will load the page with out cache.

Other way is when you change some page press <kbd>Shift</kbd> **+ click on reload button** this is usually force to reload the page even if its on cache.

All the shortcuts for diferent browsers: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

Comment: Thank you. But the problem continues.

Comment: @Tendulkrish Then you copy the files in wrong place.